# Python binascii.unhexlify TypeError: Odd-length string with non-printable character

Tags: binary, ascii, typeerror, data-conversion, binascii

I'm trying to use Python to perform binary xor operation on two strings, returning a string of ascii characters. 
I use [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) python module.
I have the following issue with the last conversion binaryString -> ASCII characters.

I have a following code:

```
byteRepList = ['01111011', '00001101']
''.join(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % int(byte, 2)) for byte in byteRepList)
```

While `01111011 => '{'`, `00001101 => nothing`.

So `TypeError: Odd-length string` is beeing thrown.

Could someone please advise, what should I properly do with it? I would still like to get string output.

Answer (score 0):

In the end my solution to this issue was just to `try-catch` the `TypeError` and `pass` in the catch block.